# How to view sub, child or inner components in the browser?

Tags: angular

This screenshot is the Left Panel, I generated **home component** **under app component**.

How can I access or view this sub component inside the browser? If I try this http://localhost:4200/app/home.component.html it only accesses app component & not home.

[image: angular demo project]

I'm new to Angular so please bear with me if this question sounds a bit off but this community is great and I could benefit others in the future.

Comment: You need to define the routes for each component. 
Here's a link to the official documentation if you're interested
https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Before you continue your trip in Angular, you should first read the getting started documentation: https://angular.io/start

Answer (score 0):

Here is the stackbliz link of basic Angular routing example please refer **app.routing.module.ts** file for clarity over this concept.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts

After that refer the official documentation for more information.
https://angular.io/guide/router